# marketing cloud - how to preview & test SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms

Does exist a capability similar to email preview and test for SMS in marketing cloud?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was added quite recently, along with the feature to send directly to Data Extensions.

You will need to create the SMS content in Content Builder.
However you can only create them in the *real* Content Builder, not from the one under Email Studio.

[image: Builder]

When you are creating your SMS message or open any of the existing ones, you'll have the option to use Subscriber Preview where you select your Data Extension and Subscriber.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You have add field called `Locale` with `Locale` to the target extension.
2. Then you can select that data extension at SMS subscribe preview mode.